# A distance over strings, and an embedding that perfectly captures it

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have an alphabet $\Sigma$. We also define a set of operations on a string $s=s_1 s_2 \dots s_n\in\Sigma^\star$ (assuming $c\in\Sigma, i\in[n]$:
$$swap(s,i)=s_1 \dots s_{i-1} s_{i+1}s_{i} s_{i+2} \dots s_n$$
$$ins(s,i,c) = s_1 s_2 \dots s_{i-1}\; c \;s_i \dots s_n$$
$$del(s,i) = s_1 s_2 \dots s_{i-1} s_{i+1} \dots s_n$$
Moreover the costs associated with each operation is defined as:
$$C_{swap(s,i)} = 2, C_{ins(s,i,c)} = |s|, C_{del(s,i)} = |s|-1$$
Now if we denote the space of all possible actions by $\mathcal{A}$, we define the distance between two strings as the minimum cost set of operations that transform one string to antoher:
$$d(s,s')=\min_{a_i\in\mathcal{A}, a_k(\dots a_2(a_1(s))\dots) = s'} \sum_{i} C_{a_i}$$

It is easy to see that the distance is symmetric, as any operation can be reversed with the same cost: $s'=swap(s,i)\rightarrow s=swap(s',i)$, $s'=ins(s,i,c) \rightarrow s=del(s',i)$ and $s'=del(s,i) \rightarrow s=ins(s',i,s_i)$, while the cost remains the same. Therefore any minimum cost list of operations could be reversed to prove $d(s,s') = d(s',s)$.

However, I have a guess that the distances have a very simple formula which is as follows:
For $s\in\Sigma^\star$ and arbitrary $a,b\in\Sigma$ we define $v_s$ as  the count of how many times letter $a$ appears before letter $b$ in the string $s$. Or formally:
$$v_s(a,b) = \#\{(i,j) \colon i<j, s_i=a, s_j=b\}$$
My guess is that:
$$d(s,s') = \sum_{a,b\in\Sigma} |v_s(a,b)-v_{s'}(a,b)| \qquad (1)$$
If this is true, another way to view it is that we can embed strings into a $|\Sigma|^2$ dimensional space $s\in\Sigma^\star\rightarrow v_s\in \mathbb{N}^{|\Sigma|^2}$, such that the $L_1$ distance in the embedding space corresponds exactly to the distance defined over strings: $d(s,s') = ||v_s - v_{s'}||_1$ (if we view $v_s,v_{s'}$ as vectors).

It is easy to see that if we get $s'$ from $s$ by a single operation, the associated cost is captured by the equation (1). But in order to prove that for any set of optimal operations the equation holds some kind of induction must be used. But I am not sure how to construct such an induction. Any ideas?